# TailwindCSS: Radio button border looks odd

Tags: tailwind-css

In Laravel, I am using TailwindCSS for styling the frontend page.

When opening the page, I have this code for creating a group of radio buttons (in this example there is only one radio button). The idea is to have a border around every radio button option. But the border looks odd and I don't have a clue why.

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:9000/checkout/select-address" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="fogk984IV9VSX7LYYsClw0kjadlauJzPMCTWY9fE" />
  <ul class="list-none">
    <li class="">
      <input type="radio" class="peer hidden" id="address_1" name="address" value="1" required />
      <label for="address_1" class="w-full cursor-pointer rounded-lg border-4 border-gray-500 p-5 peer-checked:border-blue-600">
        <div class="block">Hi</div>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

The output of this code looks like this:

[image]

I tried to use the example from this page https://flowbite.com/docs/forms/radio/#advanced-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems be due to `<label>` elements being inline elements by default. The inner block-level `<div>` element then causes the unexpected behavior of the inline element's box rendering.

Consider making the `<label>` element a block-level element by applying `display: block` via the `block` class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:9000/checkout/select-address" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="fogk984IV9VSX7LYYsClw0kjadlauJzPMCTWY9fE" />
  <ul class="list-none">
    <li class="">
      <input type="radio" class="peer hidden" id="address_1" name="address" value="1" required />
      <label for="address_1" class="w-full cursor-pointer rounded-lg border-4 border-gray-500 p-5 peer-checked:border-blue-600 block">
        <div>Hi</div>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```